# How to tell bower to get the latest version of all packages ignoring semantic versioning

Tags: node.js, bower, bower-install

This is how my bower.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Tom",
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "~2.1.10",
    "requirejs-domready": "~2.0.1",
    "ac-core": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-core.git#^0.14.1",
    "ac-grid": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-grid.git#^0.13.1",
    "ac-sparkline": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-sparkline.git#^0.6.1",
    "ac-highcharts": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-highcharts.git#^0.3.2",
    "ac-ilist": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-ilist.git#^0.4.1",
    "ac-tree": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-tree.git#^0.1.1",
    "ac-legacy": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-legacy.git",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "angular-toastr": "0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

This file was created 1 year ago. After that several changes were made to all the modules we are using and major versions of all the modules are changed now.

Because of Semantic Versioning, I am not allowed to update packages to their latest available version.

How can I force bower to update all the packages to its respective latest available version?

How can I also update `bower.json` file so that the next person trying to update the bower packages does not face the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried http://bower.io/docs/api/#install , `--force-latest` flag ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab: For some reason it did not worked.

Comment: U have the latest version of bower?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab: Bower version I am using is `1.5.3`

Comment: It does exist as a command flag, weird that it is not taking effect, event when u do `bower check-new` nothing is detected ? I know you already solved your problem, am just curious :)

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab: Though I have found a working solution, I am not sure its the right answer. Feel free to suggest options. I do not see any command like `bower check-new`. it does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Removing SemVer helped. This is how the bower.json file looks now:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Tom",
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "~2.1.10",
    "requirejs-domready": "~2.0.1",
    "ac-core": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-core.git",
    "ac-grid": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-grid.git",
    "ac-sparkline": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-sparkline.git",
    "ac-highcharts": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-highcharts.git",
    "ac-ilist": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-ilist.git",
    "ac-tree": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-tree.git",
    "ac-legacy": "git+http://ac-src/ac/bower-ac-legacy.git",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "angular-toastr": "0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```